# Slow Android Studio 1.3

Tags: android, performance, android-studio

Android Studio 1.3 latest stable update is very slow compared to its previous version 1.2.2.

I have updated Android Studio from 1.2.2 to 1.3 and it just gone slow.

It actually scans or compile or something like that all the time while typing. Its good but scanning too much makes it slow while typing.

Even it hangs for a second or two while I type something in comment.

So I want to know whether I can do something to improve performance.

**I can't downgrade :-(**

My previous version was working better. Also latest version (1.3) takes lot of time for Gradle Build.

What should I do ?

Comment: *What should I do ?*  buy better pc/mac

Comment: @Selvin I have better PC. 4th gen Intel core i5 processor. 4GB RAM. 2GB AMD Radeon Graphics. 500GB Hard Disk. Windows 8.1 OS. What else I need ?????????

Comment: Try this suggestion: http://geek.moneylover.me/android-studio-eliminate-shutter-n-lag/

Comment: My Android Studio 1.3 too is very slow. Even after a few optimizations. I run on AMD quad core A6, 4GB Ram.

Comment: I am sorry Azim but your Hardware is not enough, I have experience with really big projects and a PC with Core i7 3,4 GHZ, 8 GB Ram with normal HDD was not enough. The graphic card and the size of your HDD is irrelevant. We reduced the compiling time from 30min to 2min only changing the HDD by a Samsung SSD 850 Pro.

Comment: @MohammedAli You are using 4GB RAM which is not enough for Android studio and an emolator. I have upgraded to 6GB and Its working fast. So please increase your RAM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved my problem by just increasing **RAM from 4GB to 6GB**. Actually I was also using Genymotion which consumes almost 1GB ram and makes my PC slow. So now I have also updated Android studio to version 1.4 and updated  RAM to 6GB.

Now everything working perfect and fast Android studio as well as genymotion.

So according to me it was only a RAM shortage.

Comment: But eclipse took a lot less memory...!

Answer (score 1):

I would say to work without problems with Android Studio you need a Quadcore, 8 GB Ram 1600MHZ at least and at least a Samsung 850 Pro SSD.